# How to make async await work for a function that calls a database

Tags: node.js

I have an async function processWaitingList() that needs to wait for the result of another function findOpenVillage() that gets it's data from my database.

I'm getting the following error and do not understand why:

> (node:2620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at processWaitingList (xx\server.js:151:36) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:2620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I've read everything I can find on promises, callbacks, async and await, but I just cannot figure out how these work.

```
function slowServerLoop() {
    processWaitingList();
}
setInterval(slowServerLoop, 500);

async function processWaitingList() {
    let openVillage = await findOpenVillage();
    villageId = openVillage[0];
    openSpots = openVillage[1];
    addPlayerToVillage(waitingList[0], villageId, openSpots);
}

function findOpenVillage() {
    con.query(`SELECT id, maxVillagers FROM villages WHERE status='0'`, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result.length === 1) {
            let villageId = result[0].id;
            let maxVillagers = result[0].maxVillagers;
            con.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) as villagerCount FROM villagers WHERE villageId='${villageId}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                let villagerCount = result[0].villagerCount;
                let openSpots = maxVillagers - villagerCount;
                return [villageId, openSpots];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I was just reading that one, trying to use the suggested option: ES2017+: Promises with async/await - but can't figure out how to get it to work

Comment: You need to convert `con.query` into a Promise so you can `await` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is important thing about `await`. If you put it behind some promise, it will await the promise to be resolved and then return the value to your code.

In your case, you are not returning promise, so there is nothing to be awaited.

When you need to combine promises with callbacks (async/await is just extension over promise chains), one of way is to wrap callback inside new promise.

In your case

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
{
con.query(`SELECT id, maxVillagers FROM villages WHERE status='0'`, function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) { return reject(err); }
        if (result.length === 1) {
            let villageId = result[0].id;
            let maxVillagers = result[0].maxVillagers;
            con.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) as villagerCount FROM villagers WHERE villageId='${villageId}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) { return reject(err); }
                let villagerCount = result[0].villagerCount;
                let openSpots = maxVillagers - villagerCount;
                resolve([villageId, openSpots]);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Also remember that you need to return it (its already in code ^^ )

Comment: @ExplosionPills the function is not vulnerable to injection because it does not take any user input

Comment: @libik Thanks a lot! I could've never figured this out myself! This seems to be working!

Comment: Imagine a bad actor who is able to create a `villageId` with an injection

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I just took the OP code and wrap it with Promise, which I also described in my answer... So I dont think it make sense to evaluate the code quality itself.

Comment: This is not a question of quality, it's a question of security. I think it's reasonable to propagate good security practices in SO answers.

Comment: @ExplosionPills IMO that's not a reason for downvote. Perhaps just leave it as a comment next time so as not  to punish the answerer who doesn't get paid to answer the question in the 1st place. SO answers aren't supposed to fix secondary code issues, +1. Also I still don't see how this is vulnerable to SQL injection since it doesn't take user input but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 2):

`findOpenVillage` does not return a Promise. You need it to return a Promise in order to use `async`/`await`.

If possible, you should see if `con.query` has the ability to return a Promise. There is the `mysql-promise` library that you could use, among others. You could also use the Promise constructor yourself or the built in `util.promisify`. Let's use that last option as an example:

```
const util = require('util');

...
async function findOpenVillage() {
  const query = util.promisify(con.query);
  const maxResult = await query(`SELECT id, maxVillagers FROM villages WHERE status = '0'`);
  if (maxResult.length === 1) {
    const villageId = result[0].id;
    const maxVillagers = result[0].maxVillagers;
    const countResult = await query(
      `SELECT COUNT(*) as villagerCount FROM villagers WHERE villageId = ?`,
      villageId
    );
    const villagerCount = result[0].villagerCount;
    const openSpots = maxVillagers - villagerCount;
    return [villageId, openSpots];
  }
}
```

I've made this an `async` function so you could use `await`, but using promises with `.then` would also be reasonable. If you did that, you would have to return the promise.

---

Your original code was using string interpolation instead of parameterized queries. This makes the query vulnerable to injection. I have corrected this in my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding the parameterized queries, I'll definetely use those!

Comment: What is const util = require('util'); - what makes this method better than returning a Promise?

Comment: @PascalClaes https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original — it’s  hard to say if an approach is better than another.  You’re already using an async function, so consistentcy is nice. Async functions implicitly return Promises.

Answer (score -1):

You need to access the code after the promise is fullfilled. Your function `findOpenVillage()` must return a promise object. You need to access the values in `then`. It means that you will be accessing the values after the promise is fullfilled.

```
openVillage.then(function(response){
villageId = openVillage[0];
    openSpots = openVillage[1];
    addPlayerToVillage(waitingList[0], villageId, openSpots);
});
```

Comment: Hi, sorry you are not correct about `then`, it works same as the `await`. You are correct about returning promise though.